# Elastic Search Clustering in the Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 Linux VM's (both at same datacenter of Cloud Provider): Elastic1 and Elastic2 (where Elastic 2 is a clone of Elastic 1). Both have same version centos, same cluster name, and same version ES, again - Elastic2 is a clone.

I use the service wrapper to automatically start them both at boot, and introduced each others ip to their respective iptables file, so now I can successfully ping between nodes.

I thought this would be enough to allow ES to form a cluster, but to no avail.

Both Elastic1 and Elastic2 have 1 index each named e1 and e2 respectfully. Each index has 1 shard with no replicas.

I can use the head and paramedic plugins on each server successfully. And use `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes?pretty=true'` to validate the cluster name is the same and each server only has 1 node listed.

Is there anything glaring out at why these nodes arent talking? Ive restarted the ES service and rebooted on both servers to no avail. Could cloning be the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your elasticsearch.yml:

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ['host1:9300', 'host2:9300']
```

So, just list your node IPs with the transport port (default is 9300) under unicast hosts.  Multicast is enabled by default, but is generally impossible on cloud environments without use of external plugins.

Also, make sure to check your IP rules / security groups!  That's easy to forget.