# ElasticSearch Assign Index to Server

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 4 servers running ES where each server has 1 index with 1 shard and 0 replicas:

```
Server1: Name Server
Server2: Address Server
Server3: Health Chart Server
Server4: HealthID/SSN Server
```

I am clustering these servers in the cloud using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195116/elastic-search-clustering-in-the-cloud) disabling multicast and placing all 4 server IP's in the unicast hosts array with port 9300 works for me (on each servers config yml).

**My question is how do I set up each index to reside on its respected server (and ONLY on that Server)?** I index on each server via localhost and cannot have fault tolerance, nor do I need it. I want to cluster these servers to use an alias where I can search across all of them (that are running). If a server goes down, then so does its index. So be it -- I cannot search across it, that's fine, but I don't want the index routing to another server in the cluster, I just want it to be down. Then if I reboot the server, it rejoins the cluster and is searchable again.

I couldn't make out a solution based on the [ES Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html) which is likely oversight by me, but cannot find much on how to implement this design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious on why you want to control where a whole index is allocated. That means you don't want to have any replica (as replicas are never allocated on the same machine where the primaries are) ?
Usually shards are distributed in an even manner, thus you shouldn't need to control allocation. Anyways, for advanced use cases you can assign labels to your nodes and control where the indices are allocated via [index settings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html), have a look at [shard allocation filtering](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html#shard-allocation-filtering).