# ElasticSearch... Not So Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used this method to build Elastic Search Clusters in the cloud. It works 30%-50% of the time.

I start with 2 centos nodes in 2 servers in Digital Oceans Cloud. I then install ES and set the same cluster name in each config/elasticsearch.yml. Then I also set (uncomment):

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

as well as set and uncomment:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ['192.168.10.1:9300', '192.168.10.2:9300']
```

in each of the 2 servers. [SO Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195116/elastic-search-clustering-in-the-cloud)

Then, to give ES the benefit of the doubt, I `service iptables stop`, then restart the service on each node. Sometimes the servers see each other and I get a """cluster""" out of elasticsearch, sometimes if not most, the servers dont see each other even though multicast is disabled and specific ip addresses are given in the unicast hosts array that have NO firewall on, and point to each other.

WHY ES Community? Why does a *hello world* equivalent of elastic search prove to be inelastic to say the least (Let me openly and readily admit this MUST be user error/idiocy else no one would use this technology).

At first I was trying to build a simple 4 node cluster, but goodness gracious the issues that came along with that before indexing a single document were ridiculous. I had a 0% success rate. Some nodes saw some other nodes (via head and paramedic) while others had 'dangling indices' and 'unassigned indexes'. When I googled this I found tons of relevent/similar issues and no workable answers.

Can someone send me an example of how to build an elastic search cluster, that works?

> @Ben_Lim's Answer: Did everyone who needs this as a resource get that?
>   I took 1 node (This is not for Prod) Server1 and changed the following
>   in /config/elasticsearch.yml settings:
>
> 1. uncomment node.master: true
> 2. uncomment and set network.host: 192.XXX.1.10
> 3. uncomment transport.tcp.port: 9300
> 4. uncomment discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
> 5. uncomment and set discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.XXX.1.10:9300"]
>
> That sets the master, okay, then in each subsequent node (example
>   above) that wants to join --
>
> 1. uncomment node.master: false
> 2. uncomment and set network.host: 192.XXX.1.11
> 3. uncomment transport.tcp.port: 9301
> 4. uncomment discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
> 5. uncomment and set discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.XXX.1.10:9300"]
>
> Obviously make sure all nodes have same cluster name and you iptables
>   firewalls etc are setup right.

```
NOTE AGAIN -- This is not for prod, but a way to start testing ES in Cloud, you can tighten up the screws from here
```

Comment: the second answer in the link worked for me perfectly without any changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821101/how-to-set-up-es-cluster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most probable problem you met is the 9300 port is used by other application or the master node is not started at port 9300 , therefore they can't communicate with each other.

When you start 2 ES nodes to build up an cluster, one node must be elected to Master node. The master node will have a communication address: hostIP:post. For example:

```
[2014-01-27 15:15:44,389][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Vakume] new_master [Vakume][FRtqGG4xSKGbM_Yw9_oBLg][inet[/10.0.0.10:9302]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
```

When you need to start another node to build up a cluster, you can try to specific the master IP:port, like the example above you need to set

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.0.10:9302"]
```

Then the second node can find the master node and join the cluster.

Comment: That worked, thank you @Ben_Lim. I hope you dont mind I elaborated above for folks who may benefit from this in the future...